# (iOS) Error escaping a backslash in a string

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a problem replacing a backslash in the string `K90wuRcDX43cqDB7xkjReuzb\/nDaC0xc7Bqxi4Ft0T6EscKzEBXBJ6k8fFLl6j0S`.

If I manually escape the backslash in the string I have no problem

```
NSString *mytoken = @"K90wuRcDX43cqDB7xkjReuzb\\/nDaC0xc7Bqxi4Ft0T6EscKzEBXBJ6k8fFLl6j0S";
NSLog(@"mytoken %@",mytoken);
    mytoken K90wuRcDX43cqDB7xkjReuzb\/nDaC0xc7Bqxi4Ft0T6EscKzEBXBJ6k8fFLl6j0S
```

But if I try to do it programmatically then I can't escape the backslash (I tried with everything: CFString, `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`, `replaceOccurrencesOfString`)

```
NSMutableString *mytokenOrig = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"K90wuRcDX43cqDB7xkjReuzb\/nDaC0xc7Bqxi4Ft0T6EscKzEBXBJ6k8fFLl6j0S"];
[mytokenOrig replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:(NSRange){0,[mytokenOrig length]}];
NSLog(@"mytokenOrig %@",mytokenOrig);

mytokenOrig K90wuRcDX43cqDB7xkjReuzb/
nDaC0xc7Bqxi4Ft0T6EscKzEBXBJ6k8fFLl6j0S
```

Note: I have to append this token to a string and calculate a hash, so it's so important to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `mytokenOrig` doesn't contain a backslash, it already contains the escaped new-line.

```
[mytokenOrig replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:(NSRange){0,[mytokenOrig length]}];
```

However, you don't need to (re)escape a string. [Escape characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) are for you to be able to write special characters in code.